# How to Automate a load test simulation with different set of users using Gatling?

Tags: scala, load-testing, gatling

I have an use case wherein I have to run a simulation with 10 users followed by 20, 30, 40 so and so forth till 2000. For each set of users, I need a graph for Average response time vs number of users automatically generated. How do I automate this? Right now I have to change the number of users each time, take the response time from the graphs generated and plot it manually in an excel. How can I automate this entire flow using Gatling or any other load test tool?

Answer (score 1):

Look at the Injection documentation:

- http://gatling.io/docs/2.2.2/general/simulation_setup.html